# Flatlist not showing items as intended

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to display some items with a flatlist, when I tap on the item I want it to turn green. The issue I having is that I tap on a couple of the item and then I search for a device, for example: 112. When I remove the entry I see that the previous items are not in green anymore.
Snack: https://snack.expo.io/Skhaj78WU

```
<FlatList
   data={this.state.data}
   renderItem={({ item }) => <Item item={item}/>
   keyExtractor={item => item[0]}
   ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
   ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
   extraData={this.state.data}
/>
```

This is the Item component:

```
class Item extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state={
      currentColor:'white'
    }
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
  }

  onClick() {
    console.log(this.props.item[1].isSelected)
    console.log(this.props.item[0])
    this.props.item[1].isSelected = !this.props.item[1].isSelected
    var color = 'white'
    if (this.props.item[1].isSelected){
      color='green'
    }
    this.setState({currentColor:color})
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onClick} key={this.props.item[0]}>
        <View style={[styles.item, {backgroundColor: this.state.currentColor}]}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{this.props.item[1].name}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is causing your problems:

```
this.props.item[1].isSelected = !this.props.item[1].isSelected
```

Props should always be treated as read-only. The normal method of modifying a list from a list item is to pass a callback to each item and modify the list from the parent component, like this:

[Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@campbellmg/bossy-toffee)

```
class Item extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  getColor = () => (this.props.item[1].isSelected ? 'green' : 'white');

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onClick} key={this.props.item[0]}>
        <View style={[styles.item, { backgroundColor: this.getColor() }]}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{this.props.item[1].name}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
  toggleListItem = index => {
    const { data } = this.state;
    data[index][1].isSelected = !data[index][1].isSelected;
    this.setState({ data });
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <Item item={item} onClick={() => this.toggleListItem(index)} />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item[0]}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          extraData={this.state.data}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```